# How to share common configurations amongst Nginx server blocks?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Hosting multiple sites with the same Nginx, and a lot of them share common configurations. Such as protection against POODLE and even entire sets of redirects.

I tried using the `include` directive but that didn't seem to do the trick (it acts as if the configuration isn't even there. But Nginx -t reported no problems including the conf file and nginx reloads/restarts just fine)

Is there any good way to reuse configurations amongst multiple server blocks?

Comment: `include` should work.  That is how I do this.  Can you give more details of the configuration?